# Gmail notifier that uses Windows 10 notifications

Tags: windows, email, gmail

Can anyone recommend a Gmail notification program which:

1. Runs without a browser needing to be open (so no browser extensions)
2. Presents notifications using the Windows 10 notification system
3. Supports Google Apps
4. Is free

The best I've seen is [Gmail Notifier Pro](http://www.gmailnotifier.se/) - but that insists on using it's own pop-up system. This means that I tend to miss the notifications as the numbered icon is too subtle and the notifications don't stick around in the Windows 10 Notification Center until I dismiss them.

Comment: Have you tried just [setting up Gmail on Windows 10](https://www.simplehelp.net/2015/09/11/how-to-set-up-gmail-in-windows-10/) without any extensions? No need for your browser to be open; since it runs on windows the notifications should be native; supports contacts and calendar at the very least and is free. But I might be just misunderstanding what you are looking for, in that case, let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately when you click on the notification it then launches the mail app, rather than the Gmail website. I can't use the mail app due to an issue relating to my grandfathered Google Apps for Work too! I'm probably going to end up having to code something to meet my requirements...

Comment: Ah, ok I see. Sorry about that. I'll keep an eye out and if I find something that could fit, I will let you know.